# child: CupertinoAlertDialog flutter error

Tags: flutter

Child has an error, I tried invcache/restart, cache restart, nothing happens!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ourlm.png)

Comment: Always paste some code here so it is easy for everybody to understand,next time paste some code here@MazenLovesCoding

Answer (score 0):

Try this,let me know it is work for you

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _handleClickMe();
              },
              child: Text(
                "CLICK ME!",
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleClickMe() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: Text('Alert'),
          content: Text("Are you Sure"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            CupertinoDialogAction(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            CupertinoDialogAction(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context){
    return CupertinoAlertDialog(

    ... 
    )
  }
)
```

you didn't implement `builder: (BuildContext, context){ return Widget}`

let me know if this works for you :)